# Which of these event can be represented in either a Venn diagram and tree diagram ?

Tags: probability, trees

Which of these events can be represented in a Venn Diagram.

- Independent events
- Dependent events
- Mutually exclusive events
- Mutually independent events

Basic reasoning with example would be nice  as well.

Which of these events can be represented in a Tree Diagram.

- Independent events
- Dependent events
- Mutually exclusive events
- Mutually independent events

Basic reasoning with example would be nice  as well.

Comment: What are "mutually independent events" and how do they differ from independent events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Venn diagram**

1. Dependent events

[image]

Two events are Dependent if the occurrence of one gives us information about the other. Here If we knew that even A has occurred then we will know that event B has not occurred vice versa.

2. Independent Events

[image]

If the occurrence one event does not provide any information about the other events then the two event are said to be independent. Here if we know that event A has occurred we do not whether event B has occurred or not.

Mutually exclusive events states that if one event occurs the other event cannot occur. The above diagram for the dependent event can be used for this as well. If A occurs B cannot occur vice versa.

For mutually independent events please the following link http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/MutuallyIndependentEvents.shtml

**Tree**

Trees are used for modelling events that takes place sequentially. It is used to specify conditional probability. Tress can be used to represent both dependent events and independent events.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Thank you for clarifying this to me. Really appreciate it. Would a conditional probability be classed as dependent event ?

Comment: @JackRoberts conditional probability is used for capturing partial information that one event provides about the other (basically dependent events). Special case is when the occurrence of one event provides no information about the other (independent events).